# When 'past modal+have+past participle' accompanies with past tense in a sentence, can it be before the past or at the past?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, perfect-constructions

> Hermione, however, had more on her mind than the Sorcerer's Stone. She
>   had started drawing up study schedules and colorcoding all her notes.
>   Harry and Ron **wouldn't have minded**,[A1] but she **kept nagging**
>   [B1] them to do the same. 
>  "Hermione, the exams are ages
>   away."
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)
>
> "So you mean the Stone's only safe as long as Quirrell stands up to
>   Snape?" said Hermione in alarm.
>  "It'll be gone by next Tuesday,"
>   **said** [B2’] Ron. 
>  Quirrell, however, **must have been braver** [A2] than they'**d thought**.[B2] In the weeks that followed he did
>   seem to be getting paler and thinner, but it didn't look as though
>   he'd cracked yet. 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)
>
> She **could have wept** [A3] It was bad, it was bad, it was infinitely
>   bad! She could have done it differently of course; the colour could
>   have been thinned and faded; the shapes etherealised; that **was**
>   [B3] how Paunceforte **would have seen** [A3'] it. But then she did
>   not see it like that. She saw the colour burning on a framework of
>   steel; the light of a butterfly's wing lying upon the arches of a
>   cathedral. Of all that only a few random marks scrawled upon the
>   canvas remained. And it would never be seen; never be hung even, and
>   there was Mr. Tansley whispering in her ear, "Women can't paint, women
>   can't write ..." (Virginia Woolf, To the Lighthouse)
>
> For Cam grazed the easel by an inch; she would not stop for Mr. Bankes
>   and Lily Briscoe; though Mr. Bankes, who **would have liked** [A4] a
>   daughter of his own, **held out** [B4] his hand; she would not stop
>   for her father, whom she grazed also by an inch; nor for her mother,
>   who called "Cam! I want you a moment!" (Virginia Woolf, To the
>   Lighthouse)

I guess the tenses are like these. Which one needs to be corrected?

A1 : before Speech Time, at B1
A2 : before Speech Time, after B2, at B2’
(A2: at B2; ‘must have been’ generally coincide with the past but in this case with the past perfect?)
A3 : at B3
A3’: before B3
A4 : at B4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty nearly nailed it.

In all of these, **[past-form modal] + *have* + [past participle]** may be parsed as the 'simple past' of **[past-form modal]**.

If you "foreshift" them all into present direct speech, where Reference Time coincides with Speech Time, all your [A]s become **past forms** and all but one of your [B]s become **present forms**. I've relabeled the exception as [C2] and given you a new [B2] later in the passage:

1. "We wouldn't<sup>**A1**</sup> mind, but Hermione keeps<sup>**B1**</sup> nagging us... "
2. "It'll be gone in a week" says<sup>**B2′**</sup> Ron.  ... *a week later:*
   "Quirrell must<sup>**A2**</sup> be braver than we thought<sup>**C2**</sup>. He does<sup>**B2**</sup>n't look like he's cracked yet."
3. "I could<sup>**A3**</sup> weep. It's bad, it's infinitely bad ... that is<sup>**B3**</sup> how Paunceforte would<sup>**A3′**</sup> see it."
4. "Though Mr. Bankes, who would<sup>**A4**</sup> like a daughter of his own, is holding<sup>**B4**</sup> out his hand, I won't stop for him."

*Than they'd thought* in #2 is, as you observe, a true past perfect, lying to the past of Reference Time, and is consequently foreshifted as a past form. Reference Time for this sentence is the time *in the following weeks* when Quirrell fails to crack. In fact, your [B2], my [C2], coincides with [B2′], when Ron expressed the thought that Quirrell was not brave enough to stand up to Snape.